# Неккоректно отображается header

Tags: wordpress

Суть в чем,задали пройти открытый курс,вроде все ок,дошли до момента где нужно отредактировать,header чтобы текст страницы не залезал на него.Препод из курса сказал написать ("[image: введите сюда описание изображения]header id="masthead" class="header-main site-header " > "),а потом в css фрайле написать .header-position {  position: relative;
background-color: #D1F9FC;}.Это не помогло,на курсе так же есть люди у которых это не получилось,единственный ответ о препада был position: relative !important;,что собственно тоже не помогло.Прошу помочь в испралении этой ошибки(

```css
/*!
Theme Name: YegresTheme
Theme URI: http://underscores.me/
Author: Sergey Kutashevskiy
Author URI: http://underscores.me/
Description: Description
Version: 1.0.0
Tested up to: 5.4
Requires PHP: 5.6
License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI: LICENSE
Text Domain: yegrestheme
Tags: custom-background, custom-logo, custom-menu, featured-images, threaded-comments, translation-ready

This theme, like WordPress, is licensed under the GPL.
Use it to make something cool, have fun, and share what you've learned.

YegresTheme is based on Underscores https://underscores.me/, (C) 2012-2020 Automattic, Inc.
Underscores is distributed under the terms of the GNU GPL v2 or later.

Normalizing styles have been helped along thanks to the fine work of
Nicolas Gallagher and Jonathan Neal https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/
*/


@font-face {
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 200;
  src: url("assets/fonts/Lato/Lato-Light.ttf") format("woff2");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url("assets/fonts/Lato/Lato-Regular.ttf") format("woff2");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: url("assets/fonts/Lato/Lato-Medium.ttf") format("woff2");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  src: url("assets/fonts/Lato/Lato-Semibold.ttf") format("woff2");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: url("assets/fonts/Lato/Lato-Bold.ttf") format("woff2");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 200;
  src: url("assets/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Light.ttf") format("woff2");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url("assets/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf") format("woff2");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: url("assets/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Medium.ttf") format("woff2");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: url("assets/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Bold.ttf") format("woff2");
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #666;
}

::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #666;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #666;
}

::-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #666;
}

::placeholder {
  color: #666;
}

::-moz-selection {
  background-color: #FF6056;
  color: #fff;
}

::selection {
  background-color: #FF6056;
  color: #fff;
}

html {
  font-size: 16px;
}

input, textarea {
  outline: none;
}

input:focus:required:invalid, textarea:focus:required:invalid {
  border-color: red;
}

input:required:valid, textarea:required:valid {
  border-color: green;
}

body {
  font-size: 1rem;
  min-width: 320px;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1.65;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  color: #333;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

header {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px 56px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  z-index: 99999;
}


header .main-menu {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

header .main-menu ul {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

header .main-menu ul, header .main-menu li {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

header .main-menu li {
  margin-right: 48px;
}

header .main-menu li a {
  color: #333333;
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
}

header .main-menu li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8);
}

.hamburger {
  padding: 0;
  padding-top: 6px;
}

.hamburger-inner, .hamburger-inner:after, .hamburger-inner:before {
  background-color: #333333;
  border-radius: 0px;
  width: 38px;
}

.logo img {
  height: 20px;
}

.welcome {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("assets/img/@1x/background-home.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: left center;
}

.welcome .block {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  padding: 0 56px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
}

.welcome .block h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.welcome .block p {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  padding: 0;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
}

.m-button {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #FF6056;
  padding: 8px 48px;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  border-radius: 5%;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.m-button:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #890800;
  opacity: 0.2;
  border-radius: 5%;
  content: '';
}

.m-button:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: rgba(255, 96, 86, 0.8);
}

.head-section {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
}

.head-section a {
  color: #333333;
  font-size: 1.625rem;
}

.head-section a:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.head-section h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

.trips {
  padding: 72px 56px;
  background-color: #D1F9FC;
}

.trips .container-trips {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: start;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
      -ms-flex-align: start;
          align-items: flex-start;
}

.trips .container-trips .trip {
  width: 31%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  color: #333333;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.trips .container-trips .trip:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
          box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.trips .container-trips .trip .trip-header {
  padding: 8px;
}

.trips .container-trips .trip .trip-header h3 {
  color: #456062;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.trips .container-trips .trip .trip-header p {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  color: #727070;
}

.trips .container-trips .trip img {
  width: 100%;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
     object-fit: cover;
  height: 250px;
}

.trips .container-trips .trip .trip-footer {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  padding: 8px;
  color: #727070;
}

.about {
  padding: 72px 56px 144px;
  background-color: #D1F9FC;
}

.about .container-about {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
}

.about .container-about .about-preview {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 55%;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

.about .container-about .about-preview p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 16px;
  color: #727070;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
}

.about .container-about .about-preview img {
  width: 100%;
}

.about .container-about .about-card {
  width: 40%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
}

.about .container-about .about-card .blank {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  padding: 16px 24px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

.about .container-about .about-card .blank p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 32px;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #456062;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

.about .container-about .about-card .blank img {
  width: 56px;
}

footer {
  background-color: #333333;
  padding: 48px 56px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

footer a:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
  text-decoration: none;
}

footer ul, footer li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

footer .footer-top {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
}

footer .footer-top .logo a {
  opacity: 1;
}

footer .footer-top .social {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

footer .footer-top .social li {
  margin-left: 32px;
}

footer .footer-top .social li a {
  color: #ffffff;
}

footer .footer-top .social li a i {
  font-size: 1.75rem;
}

footer .footer-bottom {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  padding-top: 16px;
}

footer .footer-bottom .footer-menu ul {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

footer .footer-bottom .footer-menu ul li {
  margin-right: 32px;
}

footer .footer-bottom .footer-menu ul li a {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  color: #fff;
}

footer .footer-bottom .copyright {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
}

.mobile-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #D1F9FC;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-animation: open .25s ease-in 1;
          animation: open .25s ease-in 1;
}

.mobile-menu ul, .mobile-menu li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.mobile-menu li {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.mobile-menu li a {
  color: #333333;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.mobile-menu li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

@-webkit-keyframes open {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
  50% {
    width: 25%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@keyframes open {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
  50% {
    width: 25%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

.is-open {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.display-none {
  display: none;
}
.header-position {
  position: relative !important;
  background-color: #D1F9FC;
}
@media (max-width: 1399.98px) {
  header {
    padding: 16px 32px;
  }
  .welcome .block {
    padding: 0 32px;
  }
  .trips {
    padding: 72px 32px;
  }
  .trips .container-trips .trip {
    width: 32%;
  }
  .about {
    padding: 72px 32px 144px;
  }
  footer {
    padding: 48px 32px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1199.98px) {
  header {
    padding: 16px 24px;
  }
  .welcome .block {
    padding: 0 24px;
  }
  .trips {
    padding: 72px 24px;
  }
  .trips .container-trips .trip {
    width: 32%;
  }
  .about {
    padding: 72px 24px 144px;
  }
  footer {
    padding: 48px 24px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 991.98px) {
  .destkop-menu {
    display: none;
  }
  .welcome .block {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .mobile-menu {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .trips .container-trips {
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
  }
  .trips .container-trips .trip {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .trips .container-trips .trip:not(first-child) {
    margin-bottom: 16px;
  }
  .trips {
    padding: 72px 64px;
  }
  .about {
    padding: 72px 64px 144px;
  }
  .about .container-about {
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
  }
  .about .container-about .about-preview {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .about .container-about .about-card {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .about .container-about .about-card .blank {
    margin-top: 16px;
  }
  .greeting {
    width: 65%;
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes open {
    0% {
      width: 0%;
    }
    50% {
      width: 50%;
    }
    100% {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
  @keyframes open {
    0% {
      width: 0%;
    }
    50% {
      width: 50%;
    }
    100% {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
  header {
    padding: 16px 16px;
  }
  .welcome .block {
    padding: 0 16px;
  }
  .trips {
    padding: 72px 16px 72px;
  }
  .about {
    padding: 0px 16px 72px;
  }
  footer {
    padding: 48px 16px;
  }
  .greeting {
    width: 100%;
  }
  footer .footer-top .social {
    margin-left: 16px;
  }
  footer .footer-bottom .footer-menu ul li {
    margin-right: 0px;
  }
  footer .footer-bottom {
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-align: normal;
    -webkit-align-items: normal;
        -ms-flex-align: normal;
            align-items: normal;
  }
  footer .footer-bottom .footer-menu ul {
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
        -ms-flex-pack: justify;
            justify-content: space-between;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
        -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  footer .footer-bottom .copyright {
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    -webkit-align-self: center;
        -ms-flex-item-align: center;
                -ms-grid-row-align: center;
            align-self: center;
    margin-top: 16px;
  }
  footer {
    padding: 24px 16px 8px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 575.98px) {
  html {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  .about .container-about .about-card .blank {
    margin-top: 8px;
  }
  .trips .container-trips .trip {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .trips .container-trips .trip:not(first-child) {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
  }
  .logo img {
    height: 16px;
  }
  footer .footer-top .social li {
    margin-left: 16px;
  }
  footer .footer-bottom .footer-menu ul li {
    padding: 2px;
  }
  footer .footer-top .social li a i {
    font-size: 22px;
  }
  .about .container-about .about-preview p {
    padding: 8px;
  }
}
```

```html
<?php
/**
 * The header for our theme
 *
 * This is the template that displays all of the <head> section and everything up until <div id="content">
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/#template-partials
 *
 * @package YegresTheme
 */

?>
<!doctype html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="profile" href="https://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<?php wp_body_open(); ?>
<div id="page" class="site">

<header id="masthead" class="header-main site-header <?php if (!is_front_page()) echo 'header-position'?>" > 
        <div class="logo"><a href="/"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?> /assets/img//logo-black.svg" alt="Логотип"></a></div>
        <div class="main-menu">
            
            <?php
            wp_nav_menu( [
                'theme_location'  => 'top-menu',
                'container'       => 'nav',
                'container_class' => 'destkop-menu',
                'menu_class'      => '',
                
            ] );
            ?>
            
            <a href="#" class="hamburger hamburger--slider">
                <span class="hamburger-box">
                    <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
                </span>
                </button></a>
        </div>
    </header>

    <?php
            wp_nav_menu( [
                'theme_location'  => 'main-menu',
                'container'       => 'div',
                'container_class' => 'mobile-menu',
                'menu_class'      => 'm-menu',
                
            ] );
            ?>
```

Ниже представлен код header.php и style.сss Буду рада любой помощи)
Вот изображение[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуйте в css написать так 'header  .header-position'

Comment: Увы это не помогло

Comment: @Arcadiy не помогло(